# vue-material-dashboard problems with vuetify v-select

Tags: vue.js, material-design, vuetify.js

Using [vue-material-dashboard](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/vue-material-dashboard) and having problems adding [v-select(vuetify v1.5.16)](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects)

**styles are broken starting form the next DOM element**. A select element looks correct, but there is no dropdown on click.

Is there any easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vuetify require

```
<v-app>
...all the rest
</v-app>
```

root element. That was the problem.